# HTML5 app not running in Ubuntu SDK

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, html5

Today I tried to run just test program in Ubuntu SDK. I create a new project and just pressed run button. But it is showing error. And emulator is also not opening. But when I try to open with QML it is working properly.

Below is the error which I got

> Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?
>
> ubuntu-html5-app-launcher exited with code -1

What I should do to resolve this.